# Frontend (React) only solution for data structure and database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, frontend

**Problem Definition**

I am having React App with small shop where all products are coming just from **JSON file** as external **API** since I am handling everything on fronten.

But I just got in one product that has limited amount -> I have only 20psc of that product and I am not sure how I can limit the users to purchasing more than I actually have.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way (simplest possible) how I can limit amount of that product without using database or backend?
2. Is there a way how I can actually show the users how much of that specific product is left? *(imagine it as limited edition -> after every purchase number of product left will update live)*

Is that somehow possible with still using just API or do I have to revert everything into DB (**firebase** for example)?

Any suggestions and example links I appriciate!

This is how I currently handle it with unlimited amount of products

```
// fetch data here

    const fetchData = () => {
            fetch('myAPIendpoint')
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    setProducts(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };
        React.useEffect(() => {
            fetchData();
        }, []);
```

// adding product to cart

```
const onAdd = (product) => {
    const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
    if (exist) {
        setCartItems(
            cartItems.map((x) =>
                x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
            )
        );
    } else {
        setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...product, qty: 1 }]);
    }
};
```

// mapping items to show it in cart

```
 {cartItems.map((item) => (
.....
.....
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? If you use Firebase realtime DB (or Firestore) and listening to changes then it should update count for all users.

Comment: I am using just manually created API for my data.

Comment: Yes but we don't know how it works.. can you share the code so it's easier to understand?

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase then?

Comment: If more than customer is going to be using the site you need to have some way to store the result of the new total number of items after one customer buys _n_ amount so that the next customer is looking at an _updated_ total for the product. And the only way to do that is update the total for that product with an POST call to an API endpoint on a server. How you store that data is up to you.

Comment: You can just rewrite amount of product left in your JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rewrite amount of product left dirrectly in your JSON file.

ex. Somebody buying some product -> request sent to your API -> you are reading the JSON file, looking for product by id(`.find(product => producct.id === id)`). Then you are checking quantity of product (do you have needed amount or not) if not, then returning some error, if yes, then you are doing rewrite of quantity property of the product inside file for current product and do other business logic.

Work with files depends on techonlogy/programmming language you use on back-end side. You can find it separately.